# 8x8 RGB LED PWM matrix with TLC5947 which IC to use on the cathode end?

Tags: pwm, led-matrix

I made a simple LED matrix with shift registers in both row and col(anode and cathode). Now I want to build a 8x8 RGB PWM matrix so that I can control the color of each LED in the matrix.

One thing I'm struggling with is which IC to use on the cathode end. Previously, I simply added another 74HC595 and simply set row(cathode) that I wanted to light up and set RCLK. I was hoping to use the same approach, but I'm not so sure with the PWM.

I also considered using another TLC5947 but I don't think it works as source current?

EDIT: the micro controller I'm using is atmega32u4 at 16Mhz

Comment: You could use the OE (output enable) input to modulate the LED intensity with the PWM signal.

Answer (score 1):

I commend your ambition, but not your choice of projects (at your apparent level of knowledge). What you need to do is apply a PWM which varies depending on the row which is selected.

In principle this is pretty straightforward, but it's not easy. You would make 8 PWM generators, one for each column, and when you select each row you would load the appropriate PWM control value into each generator. Maybe you can go to this website:[electronic parts](http://www.componentschip.com/)

As you might guess, this will take considerable hardware. While it's true that some MCUs generate PWM outputs, I can't think of any with 8 such outputs. A compact solution would be to use an FPGA to do the job.